# corona sdk on the mac book air not working

Tags: ios, macos, coronasdk

My corona sdk on the mac book air freezes and quits suddenly when i execute this line of code.

```
jet.bodyType = "static"
```

In my windows simulator it works fine
Anybody having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What build are you using of Corona? Try updating your simulator to the most recent build.  If your using an old API that could be causing the crash.  If it isn't fixed after updating, you may have some sort of memory leak that is crashing your game.  I would file a bug report if you can't fix it since it sounds like an issue with their simulator if it works fine on Windows.  Contact `bugs@coronalabs.com`